# Creating a json with information about audio file

Tags: python

I am still new to python. I want to create a json with the related information to the audio file and also want to add the beginning and endtime to that.

A bunch of errors are showing up even though before I tried to calculate the end time everything has worked out fine.

```
import re
import speech_recognition as sr
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
import wave
import contextlib
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


def read_in():
    lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
    return json.loads(lines[0])


def myconverter(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
        return o.__str__()


def convertToString():
    # lines = read_in()
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    text = ""
    duration = 0.0
    arr = ["test2.wav", "2020-05-11 16:04:22"]
    # for item in lines:
    #     arr.append(item)

    # print(arr)
    audio = arr[0]
    timestamp_begin = datetime.strptime(arr[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    with contextlib.closing(wave.open(audio, 'r')) as f:
        frames = f.getnframes()
        rate = f.getframerate()
        # duration should be in seconds
        duration = frames / float(rate)
        print(duration)
    with sr.AudioFile(audio) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio, language='ko-kr')
        print(text)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    result = {'begin': timestamp_begin, 'end': timestamp_begin +
              timedelta(0, duration), 'audio_text': text}
    print(json.dumps(result, default=myconverter))
    print(text)


def main():
    convertToString()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I hope you can help me out. I do not know where to fix the issue.

Thank you very much.

[image: Error messages]

Comment: Please don't post code or errors in screenshots; just copy and paste it into the question (surrounded with triple backticks to preserve formatting).

Answer (score 1):

As you can see if you read the error message (always a good idea), the error happens on this line:

```py
    if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
```

It looks like you're trying to access the `datetime` *class* in the `datetime` *module* of the same name. But that doesn't work, because the import line looks like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
```

This imports those items from the `datetime` module directly into the global scope, so they become available without the `datetime.` prefix. So simply omit that prefix:

```py
    if isinstance(o, datetime):
```

---

Alternatively, import the `datetime` module wholesale:

```py
import datetime
```

And use `datetime.datetime`, `datetime.date`, `datetime.time`, `datetime.timedelta` and `datetime.datetime.strptime` (!) throughout the code. This makes it clearer where everything is coming from, at the cost of greater verbosity; the choice is yours.